# Pyspark running error

Tags: pyspark

The Spark I connected to, is not built on my local computer but a remote one. Everytime when I connect to it http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10000/, the error says:

```
[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file /usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py:
18/03/07 08:52:53 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
```

Anyways, I still keep trying to run it on Jupyter notebook:

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf())

dir(spark)
```

When I ran it yesterday, it shows directory. when I did it today, it says:

```
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you re missing the spark variable

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf())
dir(spark)
```